# Gradle fat jar does not contain libraries

Tags: java, gradle, jar, gradle-task, fatjar

I have created a simple Gradle Java project. The `build.gradle` file looks like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.10'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.6.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.6.0'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

task customFatJar(type: Jar) {
    archiveBaseName = 'fat-jar'
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}
```

I am creating the fat `jar` according to https://www.baeldung.com/gradle-fat-jar.

However, the resulting jar does not contain the `commons-lang3` library. It only contains the project's class files.

Why isn't my library included in the fat `jar`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The guide from Baeldung is outdated. I suggest following the guide in the official user guide instead: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/building_java_projects.html#sec:java_packaging

They are currently suggesting this:

```
task uberJar(type: Jar) {
    archiveClassifier = 'uber'

    from sourceSets.main.output

    dependsOn configurations.runtimeClasspath
    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.findAll { it.name.endsWith('jar') }.collect { zipTree(it) }
    }
}
```

You can customize the name like you already did, if you don't like using properties like `archiveClassifier`.

If you are interested in why the Baeldung version doesn't work for you, it is because they collect dependencies from the deprecated configuration called `compile`. You are using the newer `implementation` instead, so `compile` is empty. However, instead of simply changing `compile` to `implementation`, it is recommended to use `runtimeClasspath` (like in the user guide) as this will correctly handle dependencies that are scoped to only the compile phase or as runtime only. While you don't have any of those now, you may in the future.

Comment: +1000,  all other answers put `configurations.compile.*`